# Naan not sticking to tandoor walls

Tags: bread, oven, curing

I am having trouble getting my naan bread to stick to the tandoor walls. (Yes, I've tried adding water) I have made the same recipe twice with no issues and now the third time around it doesn't want to stick. I have not seasoned/cured the tandoor, could that be the issue? if so, what is a simple way of doing that? or was the tandoor just simply not hot enough...or maybe too hot?

Comment: What temperature was your tandoor?

Comment: @GdD I'm honestly not exactly sure.

Comment: @GdD is a specific temperature needed for it to stick? it defiantly seemed hot enough when felt inside

Answer (score 5):

A tandoor is generally at least 500°C, that's 930°F, so it's most likely your tandoor was not hot enough. An infrared thermometer is your friend here, it will take the guesswork out of it.

Also, your naan dough needs to be sticky, if it doesn't stick to your hand it's not going to stick to the tandoor wall. If it's not sticky enough spritz some water on it. You also need to really smack it up against the side.